# search options for non-file org links?

Tags: org-mode, org-link

orgmode file links can contain additional information to link to particular places within a file, i.e.:

```
[[file:~/code/main.c::255]]
```

opens main.c and jumps to line 255. Is it possible to accomplish this with non-file links? I'm particularly interested in links to man pages, provided via `org-man`. I'd like to be able to link directly to a line or heading within a long man page, such as `man bash`.

The following doesn't work:

```
[[man:bash::144][bash manual line 144]]

[[man:bash::OPTIONS][bash manual options section]]
```

Is it possible to define a link handler to incorporate searching as is done with the built-in file links?

Comment: You can define it by yourself. Check out function `org-link-set-parameters`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out-of-the-box (i.e. with `org-contrib`), it seems to be possible with, say, `info` links (where you can link to a specific section, as `info:filename#nodename-or-index`), but not with `man` links. Looking at the source corroborates that: [info](https://github.com/emacsmirror/org/blob/27e5beaa64a0720e4935d68da2dd61de79762f4e/lisp/org-info.el), [man](https://github.com/emacsmirror/org/blob/27e5beaa64a0720e4935d68da2dd61de79762f4e/contrib/lisp/org-man.el).

In principle, there is no reason why you couldn't define your own org link handler, based on `org-man` linked above. In particular, you'd need a custom definition of `org-man-open`. (If you don't care about exporting from `org` and don't need `org-store-link` to be clever, then you don't really need to modify anything else.) Since AFAICT neither `man` nor `woman` supports opening at a specific line or specific section of a manpage, directly, you'll need a function to search for a string or go to the Nth line in the opened manpage. `org-link-search` and `org-link-line` might perhaps be helpful. (Depending on whether you prefer `man` or `woman` you might be bitten by the fact that `man` line numbers depend on the width of your window. Searching should work without issues.)